# Different behaviour of browsers while caching the same file

Tags: php, caching

I am trying to implement `mod_disk_caching`. I wrote a php code as shown in the example of the tutorial I was following.

I fired the following in the terminal

```
a2enmod cache
a2enmod disk_cache

/etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload

then in the php code 

<?php
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=3000");
header("Vary: Accept-Encoding");
echo time()."<br>";
?>
```

Now I tried running it using firefox.

In the first execution I got the following timestamp.

1308643975

Here, when I press refresh, the timestamp changes (as the file is reloaded from the server)
and remains the same when I click the link again (as the file is retrieved from the cache).

Now I am trying the same with `IExplorer`.

As per my understanding, the timestamp should be the same as the subsequent request for the file will be retrieved only from the cache. But I got a different timestamp.

Can anyone explain me the reason for this? Why is it giving separate timestamps when the browsers are different?

Comment: <?php
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=3000");
header("Vary: Accept-Encoding");
echo time()."<br>";
?>

Comment: that is the php code being executed

Answer (score -1):

try to add more headers: "Expires", "Pragma",